# Serialized array, grab specific posts with meta_key/meta_value[0]->is_featured

Tags: get-posts, array

I've a postmeta key saved in DB: `mediSHOP_product_extras`
It's value is

Unserialized: `Array ( [0] => Array ( [is_slider] => 0 [is_featured] => 0 [in_stock] => 0 [video_url] => [related_product_list] => ) )`

For simplicity I didn't want to save each value as a new key/value combination in DB. But I might have made a mistake...

I want to use get_posts to fetch posts that have `is_featured == 1` And I cannot figure out how to do this...

```
$slides_content = get_posts(array(
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 12,
    'meta_key'       => 'mediSHOP_product_extras',
    'meta_value'  => '1'
));
```

meta value needs to be 1, but it also needs to be `is_featured == 1`.

Simplest solution would be to just save is_featured as a separate key. But maybe you know how to solve my problem?

Comment: A good rule of thumb to follow is: if you need to query by a meta key, don't store it serialized.

Comment: @helenhousandi I realized that, in fact I moved to using taxonomy for this... which is faster and better organized for this kind of tasks.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible if you shape your meta query to look for the serialized string like this, assuming your array value is always an integer:

```
$params = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'mediSHOP_product_extras',
            'value'   => 's:11:"is_featured";i:1;',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
);
$query = new \WP_Query( $params );
```

If the array value is a string or a boolean, the meta query value pattern should be altered:

```
// for string type values
's:11:"is_featured";s:1:"1";'

// for bool type values
's:11:"is_featured";b:1;'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think below code will work for you

```
$args = array(
   'post_type' => 'post',
   'meta_key' => 'mediSHOP_product_extras',
   'posts_per_page' => '12',
   'meta_query' => array(
       array(
           'key' => 'mediSHOP_product_extras',
           'value' => '1',
           'compare' => '=',
       )
   )
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);

if u face any problem let me know.
```

Comment: But, mediSHOP_product_extras = Array ( [0] => Array ( [is_slider] => 0 [is_featured] => 0 [in_stock] => 0 [video_url] => [related_product_list] => ) )

How will that query understand that I need to look at "is_featured" key inside mediSHOP_product_extras?